# Problem Ubuntu putting out characters in both UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1

Tags: locale, putty, utf-8, ncurses, letsencrypt

I use PuTTY to connect to my Xubuntu system. When I set the translation to UTF-8 the fancy output from systemd looks fine but a ncurses application show up oddly. When I set the translation in PuTTY to ISO-8859-1 (Western European) the ncurses program look perfect and the output from systemd has the odd characters.

1. Which application is behaving badly?
2. Is there a way of forcing either application to be compatible with the other?

Comment: Obviously, your "ncurses application" outputs ISO-8859-1. If your locale is set to UTF-8, then the application is the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need setup few environment variables to customize programs to your language and country. Here you are an article about [**Locales**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale). In short:

- Run `locale` to check current values, they must match with PuTTY's translation settings.
- If the translation in PuTTY is set to UTF-8 and (for example) your language is Bulgarian, you need to set `bg_BG.UTF-8` into your locales (if it's not). You can do that through next steps:

  - generate missing locales:

    ```
    sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
    ```
  - reconfigure locales:

    ```
    export LANG=bg_BG.UTF-8
    ```
  - Then you can adjust some desired locale categories. For example you can turn the translated terminal messages back in English via:

    ```
    export LANGUAGE=en_EN.UTF-8
    ```
- If the things looks right, you can put above (export) commands into the end of `~/.bashrc` file and they will be loaded for each future session.
- According to the [@fkraiem's comment above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868881/problem-ubuntu-putting-out-characters-in-both-utf-8-and-iso-8859-1/868896#comment1345821_868881) for some apps ([like as GNU Dialog](https://superuser.com/questions/333388/gnu-dialog-and-utf-8-characters)) you must add and this line into the end of `~/.bashrc`:

  ```
  export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1
  ```

Hope that will help.

Comment: The environment variable was what I needed, thanks.

Comment: There is no reason to set the `LC_ALL` variable persistently. `LANG` is sufficient if you don't want different locales for different locale categories.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson You are right. I've improved a bit my answer. Thanks.